# how to use image in ios with Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I use Xamrin forms for an app on IOs and Android.

in my Android project and IOS project, i have a folder "drawable" (with my image) in the "resources" folder.

In my XAML i call like this :
`<Image Source="@drawable/clockCircular.png"/>`

When attempting to view the image on Android, no problem I see my image.
When attempting to view the image on iOS, the image doesn't appear.

I would like to keep this file structure (resources > drawable).
I have followed many tutorials on the web as [images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/) but I'm still blocked here.

Comment: Before asking a question please get familiar with the official Xamarin.Forms documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Resources > drawable` structure for android and you need put image in `Resources` folder of iOS project and also verify File name is correct and not used any special symbol.

**Edit**

You need to set image source like below no need to add specify `drawable` Both platforms iOS(Resources) and Android (Resources > drawable) taken automatically.

```
<Image Source="clockCircular.png"/>
```

Comment: TY, in fact after i put image in Resources  for IOS (i have delete my sub-folder) and after i replace <!-- language: lang-xml -->
<Image Source="@drawable/clockCircular.png"/> by <Image Source="clockCircular.png"/>, it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

IOS => You need put the images on "Resources"  (note: no more routes)
ANDROID => you need put the images on "Resources/drawable" .

On Diferents platforms the images have diferents routes.

Then on the xaml files you can put `<Image Source="imageName.jpg" />`